# append string parmeters while submitting a GET form from HTML

Tags: html, forms, submit-button

Consider a form in Html:

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:7px;">
        <label class=".... </label>
        <input type="text" name="prefersite1" placeholder="http://www.website.com">
        <input type="text" name="prefersite2" cla....;">
        <input type="text" name="prefersite3" cl....">
        <input type="text" name="prefersite4" c....">
        <input type="text" name="prefersite5" cla....">
    </div>
```

On using a 'submit' type button, is there a way to get appended prefersite_list[] or comma separated string in the url
The button I used is just:

```
<button type="submit">
    Submit
</button>
```

I am working on django platform and use this url to extract variables by request.GET.get method in python. Is there a way to change name=prefersite[0], [1] etc so that I will get a single long string.

Instead of `/?prefersite1=&prefersite2=&prefersite3=..` , I need a single `/?prefersite=`.
Using prefersite[] as name seems to be working for post forms, but I need to use get forms.

Comment: If you use `GET` method all the form elements appended to the URL right? Did you require anything else?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the `submit` type button..? it seems that you haven't even tried anything. try something, check whats happening, do some research, still if you are facing an issue… bring it to the community explaining what you've tried, what's happening and how you want it to be...

Comment: I've used submit button on localhost, for ex the following url will http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/?prefersite1=&prefersite2=&prefersite3=&prefersite4=&prefersite5=
rather I'd like a single /?prefersite=. As there are many such variables in the html code, getting request in a single argument is much needed.